# Packing 16-bit color values for DXT texture compression

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am working on a 3-D graphics library primarily in c# (with some embedded native c++ libs beneath an interop layer) and I am trying to keep the interop layer as thin as possible and as high-performance as possible.

I've created some structs in the c# interop layer for working with DXT texture compression (DXT1, DXT3 and DXT5 presently) which get passed to native libs for marshalling to the GPU.

For doing so, some "helper" structs are required to help format the data properly due to the fact that the 16-bit RGB color input values used with DXT are in the bit-format of R:5 G:6 B:5.

My question is in regards to the struct I have created to hold these 16-bit RGB values. The struct (DXTColor16) holds the packed values as an unsigned 16-bit integer (ushort) and exposes the individual color components as byte value properties which use bit-ops to get and set values to and from the packed value internally.

From the example of this struct below, can anyone suggest a more efficient way to handle the packing/unpacking of values within the struct?

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper struct for a 16-bit color of a DXT1, DXT3 or DXT5 block.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>Dependent on little endian byte ordering.</para>
/// <para>For cross-platform compatability, this will need to be redesigned to account for endianness when packing/unpacking values.</para>
/// </remarks>
public struct DXTColor16
{
    private const byte MAX_5_BIT = 0x1F;    // 00011111
    private const byte MAX_6_BIT = 0x3F;    // 00111111

    private const ushort B_MASK = 0x1F;    // 0000000000011111
    private const ushort G_MASK = 0x7E0;   // 0000011111100000
    private const ushort R_MASK = 0xF800;  // 1111100000000000

    /// <summary>
    /// Red color component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Red color component is 5-bit.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public byte R
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte)((Value & R_MASK) >> 11);  // extract R value and shift into byte value.
        }
        set
        {
            var r = (value & MAX_5_BIT) >> 11;  // trunc input to 5 valid bits and shift into place for masking when combining during set Value.
            var val = Value & (~R_MASK);        // clear existing R value with inverted R_MASK.
            Value = (ushort)(r | val);          // set Value.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Green color component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Green color component is 6-bit.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public byte G
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte)((Value & G_MASK) >> 5);   // extract G with G_MASK and shift into byte value.
        }
        set
        {
            var g = (value & MAX_6_BIT) >> 5;   // trunc input to 6 valid bits and shift into place for masking when combining during set Value.
            var val = Value & (~G_MASK);        // clear existing G value with inverted G_MASK.
            Value = (ushort)(g | val);          // set Value.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blue color component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Blue color component is 5-bit.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public byte B
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte)(Value & B_MASK);  // extract B with B_MASK and return as byte value.
        }
        set
        {
            var b = value & MAX_5_BIT;      // trunc input to 5 valid bits. No shift needed, already in place for masking.
            var val = Value & (~B_MASK);    // clear existing B value with inverted B_MASK.
            Value = (ushort)(b | val);      // set Value.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Packed 16-bit unsigned integer containing the blue, green and red color components.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Color components are in R|G|B order.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public ushort Value;
}
```

Could I be handling the bit-wise operations in a more efficient way? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that this code is correct: new `Value` doesn't depend on old `Value` in set blocks. I would expect something like `var r = (value & MAX_5_BIT) >> 11; Value = Value & (~R_MASK); Value = Value | r;` (not tested)

Comment: ah yep, typo. val is meant to be a masked copy of Value, not the value input param and the assignment was meant to be an OR not an AND. Updated with edit. Thank you.

Comment: I think this code is OK. You may add saturation logic if you want - not for better performance, just for convenience, so that `set` with value > maximal gives maximal value. Additionally, function which sets all three components together is both convenient and performs better than setting R, G and B with properties.